# Add class to first child - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very simply trying to add a class to the element `.page-item-39 a` using Javascript but i'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined", what is the reason for this?

```js
var menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName('page-item-39');
  var menuLink = menuItem.firstChild;
  console.log(menuLink);
  menuLink.className += ' menu-item-active';
```

```css
.menu-item-active {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<li class="page_item page-item-39">
    <a>Classes</a>
</li>
```

Comment: you could just use the css psudo selecor `:nth-child(1)`. Aka: `page-item-39>:nth-child(1)`

Comment: If you want to add it to the *first* `.page-item-39 a` element: `document.querySelector(".page-item-39 a").className += " menu-item-active";` If you want to add it to all `.page-item-39 a` elements, you'll need to loop through the list returned by `getElementsByClassName` (or `querySelectorAll`, which would probably make more sense here as you want the `a` within the `.page-item-39`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `[0]` instead of `firstChild` on menuItem.

```js
var menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName('page-item-39');
  var menuLink = menuItem[0];
  console.log(menuLink);
  menuLink.className += ' menu-item-active';
```

```css
.menu-item-active {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<li class="page_item page-item-39">
    <a>Classes</a>
</li>
```